# stack overflow data dump utility error - mysql

Tags: support, data-dump, stackoverflow

I have the SODDI v.11 utility (although the screen says v.10)

I also have the SODD from 092011.

When I try to import the SF/MSF data, I get:

> Table 'SF.VoteTypes' doesn't exist.

It creates the SF database and the following tables:

- `posttags`
- `posttypes`
- `votetypes`

I've also dropped the `votetypes` table and created the same table as `VoteTypes` (case sensitive), and get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The case sensitivity in the error message turns out to be the culprit.

I had to disable case sensitive table names in MySQL on a linux host. In the my.cnf, add `lower_case_table_names = 1`. Restart MySQL. This bypasses the case sensitivity of the underlying file system for storing the MySQL data.

I was on the right track by trying to maually create the table with case sensitivity, but the doc shows that the database is dropped and created, so any change I had made was dropped.